# ASP.NET GridView | How to build a footer like exact copy of header? (Visual and Methods)

Tags: asp.net, gridview, header, footer

I´m extending the Gridview. Right now, i have this:
[image]

My goal is to change it till i get this (Paint):
[image]

I think that it can be done thru the "OnRowCreated". But dont have a clue on how.

```
    protected override void OnRowCreated(GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRowCreated(e);

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {


        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me out on this one?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question in JonH's comments, if there is an easier way to put the header's text into the footer, set every footer's cell-text same as header (Vb.Net):

```
   Private Sub MyGrid_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
            Dim header As GridViewRow = DirectCast(sender, GridView).HeaderRow
            For i As Int32 = 0 To header.Cells.Count - 1
                Dim headerCell As TableCell = header.Cells(i)
                Dim footerCell As TableCell = e.Row.Cells(i)
                footerCell.Text = headerCell.Text
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

You should use the same CssClass on HeaderStyle and FooterStyle to apply the same style.

If you want to add controls dynamically(like the Checkbox in your image), you should use RowCreated-Event instead(like Tomas Voracek suggested), because controls must be regenerated on every postback and RowDataBound gets only called when you bind the datasource to the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Just change it to

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header ||  e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
  // add cells to row
}
```

Comment: You do not need to add Cells, they are added as long as you set the Showfooter property for the grid view to true.  Then you simply use the RowDataBound event to check if you are on the footer and assign / add labels or fields to each cell.

Comment: @JonH: You shouldn't add controls in the RowDataBound-Event because they must be readded on every postback, so you would use RowCreated for dynamical controls in the header. RowDataBound typically only gets called if `!IsPostBack`.

Comment: @Tim that part is true you are right you want to use RowCreated.

Answer (score 0):

Set the gridview's ShowFooter property to true.
Then you have the right idea, you'll want to first give some style to your footer as it will only appear as white when you set ShowFooter=True.

Once you apply some CSS to the footer property settings you will see some color.
The in the RowCreatedEvent event do a check:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      //dont do anything
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
      e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "MyCol1";
      e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "MyCol2";
      e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "MyCol3";
    }
```

[Here's an article in case you need additional help](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/displaying-summary-information-in-the-gridview-s-footer-cs)

Comment: First, Thank you all. Now, I'm in the right path. But the last question: How to populate the footer labels with the ones on the header? (not manually). I already try the HeaderRow.Cells[i].text but without sucess :(

Comment: @pee - simple you have another if to check if you are on DataControlRowType.Header.  If you are snatch all values and store in a string array or a list of type List<string>, once populated you use that to fill in the values for the footer.

Comment: Is there a better/elegant way to do it? I´m asking because i need to copy the methods asociated (Like the first checkbox which select them all)